# Read/load JSON in Javascript WHERE 'id' = 'x'

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I currently have a piece of code that loads all the info from a .json file into an array in JavaScript.

```
    function loadContacts(filter) {
    var contacts = (function () {
     var contacts = null;
     $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'userdata/' + username + '.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            contacts = data;
        }
    });
   return contacts;
   })();

  //filter code goes here, not necessary for this example

  }
```

I have an ID number stored in a variable, for this example `userid = 99`. Below is an example of my `.json` file

```
[{"firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"Butterworth","id":"99"},{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","id":"101"}]
```

How can I edit the `loadContacts` function above to read/load ONLY the .json info where the **id** is **99**? So the `loadContacts` function above will return `{"firstName":"Ryan","lastName":"Butterworth","id":"99"}` into `contacts`?

Comment: Do you expect the data in the JSON file to change often?

Comment: The JSON file only changes on user input from a completely separate page. But yes it could possibly change often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to do exactly that...

```
contacts = contacts.filter(function(i) {
    return i.id == "99";
});
```

It returns a new array, after iterating through the existing one and only adding the items that return true from the function.

I'm going to hold back from the synchronous & asynchronous conversation, but I think the fact this comment is here gives you an idea how I feel about it :p